# Read a file.dat and display as Hebrew Text

Tags: c#, file, binaryfiles

I have a Dat File that is like so:

```html
? ur [IM?&v?  xp         p      Z   
   2      0      1      vuq ~      uq ~           u      a   
   ;      <      ;      wr [[BK??g?  xp   ur [B???  xp   A*.9
 7 eL
% *> .9
%  *> 0!d1uq ~    y U!d 0
> Y M  F   /9.!A "65&*7
 L %  7 / eF
% /!95! "65&*>
 0
%1uq ~    0 
>! e9
% 

6L   0

60 1uq ~    d 
z e`
% !69  '
6IL   
-*7 eF
% *>
3 9   *>
3 /0.!A1uq ~    p 
4Y eV
%a  M 
F %  /9.!A 47 L
  0

6"!>!  0

694! 
> % !/0-1uq ~    c 
7! eF
% 
>
 49
" 7 A L
%  
7
 -F
 *>
3 9
% 0
%1uq ~    ?
7"Q e
%?!604?"? 
-*U *V
3 Y
%M :.!M 7/ 04F
"  *7
3 F
% :.!9 *"7 04L
"  0

6'*031uq ~    Z 
4z e`
% 049
" .L
%  0

6"!>!  0

694! 
> % .*&0
1uq ~    | 
7! eU
% 
4 Y  s
% V/ .Y
%M !647 % !/F-  *0!9 
.L  0

6'*031uq ~    s 
4Y eV
%a 
.M !F!d  4 *> 9
% 47 
L
%  
> e9
% '
6I0 1uq ~    ?
7! eU
% 0-.*V Y!dM -!U.! "?Q! @7
" @!F" "*7d 5? "VQ! 5
M 
&F  :.!> @" 69  "6L!d  0

6'*031uq ~    ? ?*Y s!d -?.! "*7Q! @V
" @!Y"M 
&*F   "*zd "0Q!65`
 :.!> @" 69  
&*L   
> e9
% '
6I0 1uq ~    2 0

6"!>!  0

694! 
> % .
.0
1uq ~    ?
7! eU
% 
V
 M 47
" .F
% -? *>
3 
9 %  *7
3 L
  
V  M  7 ":-F
%  
9
%  .&0
%1uq ~    S 
V   M 47
" .F
% 9
 "6L!d  0

6'*031uq ~    ?
7"Q eF
% !6.&*>
 9 ;-L
% !6V  ;-M !.!7! 
F %  !6V  4I3M !.!7! F
  *9 '0 '0
%1uq ~    L 
*>3 `% e9
% 47
" .L
% 9
 "60!d1uq ~    u .M 
7 %  F
  0-F
 *>
```

I have tried, without success to display the Hebrew Text that this converts to with the Code:

```
Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
var count = binaryReader.BaseStream.Length / sizeof(int);
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
byte[] Hebrew = binaryReader.ReadBytes(8);
this.richTextBox1.AppendText(hebrewEncoding.GetString(Hebrew));
}
}
}
```

I am not able to display the text as it should be. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Where did the file originate from? It is probably the encoding you are using in the BinaryReader

Comment: Yes, I have tried different Encoding, maybe just not hit the right one. File is from some old SW Package that no longer runs on windows. I am trying to reserect the data.

Comment: Binary data files cannot be simply converted to text.  They are a mixture of text and numbers that have specific field lengths and/or terminators.  Without the specification defining the binary format I would only be guessing how to parse the data.

Comment: Do you still have the old software package? If so, it may be worth spinning up a Virtual Machine to run it. Alternatively, look at the compatibility modes available under Windows; see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/support

Comment: Incomplete install, some files missing or corrupt, was a recovery from an Old Bad Hard Drive.